# migrate deprecated promise-handling code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have some code that handles Angular promises like this

```
somethingThatReturnsAPromise
  .then(function (data) {
    // handle success  
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always do this
  });
```

I understand this syntax is deprecated now, and this code should be replaced with

```
somethingThatReturnsAPromise.then(
  function (data) {
    // handle success  
  },
  function (error) {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

But where should I put the code that was previously in `finally` when using this new syntax, i.e. code that is executed both when the promise is resolved (successful) and rejected (fails)?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: I'd be surprised if catch and finally were deprecated

Comment: Nonetheless, catch(f) = then(null, f) and finally(f) = then (f, f)

Comment: `.catch()` is part of the ES6 promises specification.  I'd be surprised if anyone was deprecating it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with `then` either way, you can provide a handler for both success and error promise handlers:

```
function always() {
    // Do whatever either it fails or succeeds
}

somethingThatReturnsAPromise.then(always, always).then(function(data) {

}, function(error) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1st: I didn't find anything about any (Promise-related) method being deprecated in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

2nd: `finally` is way more complicated then a `then(cb, cb)`, since it doesn't catch Errors, and doesn't propagate the results of your callback, but if you return a promise, it waits for this promise to resolve until it continues propagating the current value.

Sth like this:

```
function _finally(promise, callback) {
    var handleValue = isError => value => $q((resolve, reject) => {
        //call your callback
        //if this throws, propagate the Error
        var w = typeof callback === "function" && callback();

        //prepare to push the current value/error
        var fn = isError?
            () => reject(value):
            () => resolve(value);

        //check wether your callback has returned sth. Promise-like
        if(w && typeof w.then === "function"){
            //then we'll wait for this to resolve, 
            //before we continue propagating the current value/error
            w.then(fn, fn);
        }else{
            //otherwise propagate the current value/error emmediately
            fn();
        }
    });

    return $q.resolve(promise).then(
        handleValue(false),
        handleValue(true)
    );
}
```

I wrote this code only to give you an implession what `finally` does. Angular's implementation is smoother, so stick with that.

I don't see any reason to think that `catch` or `finally` are deprecated or will ever be.